# PHP variable creating link for button

Tags: php

So I wanted to make an easy way for me to see my school projects. I tried to make in webpage HTML input and output as a clickable link that contains mysite.com/"Input".I tried using PHP variable probably in wrong way.

I tried using PHP variables to make output for the button.

```
<input type="button" value="View item" onClick="parent.location='/view/<?PHP echo $output ?>.html'"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: So what's the problem you are running into?

Comment: What exactly is the question? What value is $output containing when you run the above code? Was is in parent.location during runtime?

Comment: I can't use PHP variable to create/generate a link.That would send you to another folder on the website.

Comment: use `<?php` not `<?PHP`

Comment: @Edwin The tag itself is case insensitive

Comment: Please show the code where you define `$output`

Comment: @Edwin Both `<?PHP` and `<?php` work. Even `<?pHp` works.

Comment: I know (I didn't say that's the answer), but as a recommendet php standard (http://www.php-fig.org/psr/) he should use `<?php`. The same reason you don't write all the code in one line. Back on topic: does your server with php is up and running?

Comment: @Edwin Yes, it's running locally, with PHP 7.1.3

Comment: show us more of your code, like what is in `$output`, in what file type is this code, errors that you get and what's your problem

Comment: @Kaspars so, what does show with that code you're using? TBH, I'm having trouble figuring out what it is that you're trying to do here. You want to make your site show up when you click that button? There also appears to be a lot of missing code.

Comment: *"So I wanted to make an easy way for me to see my school projects."* - Well, that calls for an external HTTP call and your `/view/` is "local". You were asked over an 1/2 hour ago to post what the `$output` variable is and assigned as, but failed to respond to them. I won't be standing around as long as others have and will now find my way out and with a vote to close as unclear; good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although i do not know how you are going to fetch the php variable and from where, i am giving an option. you can write the function like this:

```
 <?php
       $input_vars = 'some-place';

     ?>
        <button onclick="onclickRedirect()">redirect</button>
    <script>
       function onclickRedirect(){
          window.location.href = "http://www.yoursite.com/<?php echo $input_vars ?>";
    }

    </script>
```

make sure you do all in a php file. hope this will help you.

Comment: glad that helped